# How to vertically align two elements inside a multirow

Tags: multirow

I would like to include a centered “(a)” above an image `\includegraphics{test.png}` both inside a multirow cell.

I have tried a `\break` command:

```
\multirow{2}{*}{(a)\break\includegraphics{test.png}}
```

it didn't worked. I tried to include a `tabular`environment

```
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{c}(a)\\\includegraphics{test.png}\end{tabular}}
```

it broke my compilation.

Here is the result I want to obtain:

[image]

I'm using the following format for the `tabular` environment :

```
@{}p{.144\textwidth}p{.049\textwidth}p{.617\textwidth}p{.09\textwidth}@{}
```

What I need is to place the "(a)" and "(e)" above the images…

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please add some background information on the intended use for this? Are you actually interested in adding a subcaption to an image? What else is in your tabular, apart from the `\multirow` command?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following that could serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text. Do not use in real document.

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
(a)  \\
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{lp{5.5cm}}
(b) & \lipsum[1][1]\\
(c) & \lipsum[1][3]\\
(d) & \includegraphics[width=1cm,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
(e)  \\
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```